# count file wise as well as datewise in Map reduce Python

Tags: python, split, mapreduce, mapper, reducers

I have a mapper that gives me words like,

```
apple 10 12012013
apple 20 12022013
apple 30 12042013
apple 40 12032013
```

where the first value is the word, followed by occurence of that word on that day mentioned in the 3rd column.

I have written a reducer which can pick the key as apple and then get its total count.

so the output is like this

```
apple 100
```

But I need to output as,

```
100 apple 12012013:10 12022013:20 12032013:30 12042013:40
```

Any idea how should I modify my mapper ?

I am running this Map reduce job on Amazon EMR Hadoop Streaming.

EDIT: The below code works perfectly, but I am getting the output as :

```
4   apple   20130601
:1  20130602
:1  20130601
:1  20130602
:1
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you change the `split()` call to something else? If that's the case then add a `rstrip` call before applying `split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
>>> with open('filename') as f:
    dic = {}
    for line in f:
        name, quan, dt = line.split()
        dic.setdefault(name, []).append((dt, quan))
...         

>>> for k, v in dic.items():
    total = sum(int(x[1]) for x in v)
    print '{} {} {}'.format(total, k, ' '.join('{}:{}'.format(x, y) for x, y in v))
...     
100 apple 12012013:10 12022013:20 12042013:30 12032013:40
```

If the data with same product is always grouped together than you can also use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> with open('abc1') as f:
    for k, g in groupby(f, key=lambda x:x.split()[0]):
        data = [x.split()[1:] for x in g]
        total = sum(int(x[0]) for x in data)
        print '{} {} {}'.format(total, k, ' '.join('{}:{}'.format(y, x) for x, y in data))
...         
100 apple 12012013:10 12022013:20 12042013:30 12032013:40
```

**Update:**

If the input is coming from a file stream then you can use `sys.stdin`:

```
import sys
from itertools import groupby
for k, g in groupby(sys.stdin, key=lambda x:x.split()[0]):
    ...
```

Comment: This works locally. But I need to modify my reducer where the input is given by Hadoop streaming. So logic is a little different. I am thinking to use your help to modify into the reducer I have.

Comment: @pa1geek If the data is coming from a stream than you can simply replace `f` with `sys.stdin`.(And also remove the `with` statement part.)

Comment: This works perfectly except that it prints values in different lines when I try to print it. something like this : 
    4 apple 20130601\n
    :1 20130602\n
    :1 20130601\n
    :2 20130602\n